# How to pass text from one form to opened form at back?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have two forms. One is InvoiceEntry and another is ListofSuppliers. There is a control "txtsnam" in InvoiceEntry.ListofSuppliers contains a Datagrid which has all the names of suppliers. When user presses f9 on this textbox ListofSupplier form is opened. The user select the name of supplier from grid and press enter. On this press enter i want to pass the name of supplier to the "txtsnam".I have used this code but its not working for me:

On InvoiceEntry:

```
Private Sub txtsnam_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles txtsnam.KeyDown`
       If e.KeyCode = Keys.F9 Then
            Dim lov As New SupplierLOV
            lov.ShowDialog()
        End If
End Sub
```

On ListofSuppliers:

```
Private Sub RadGridView1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles RadGridView1.KeyDown
If e.keycode=keys.Enter then
   InvoiceEntry.txtsnam.text=RadGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString
  End If
End Sub
```

I also tried with the help of property but its also not working. I placed the breakpoint on line 2 it executes bt text doesnot appear in txtsnam

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: Create an event in Form2 and subscribe to it in Form1 when you open the Form2. When pressing on the Return key, raise the event in Form2 and transmit the value as parameter. Form1 will receive your value.

Solution 2: Add a member to Form2 of type Form1 and pass Form1 as parameter to Form2 when you create Form2. In this way you have full access to Form1 properties and you can set it from code anytime. When you close Form2 you already have your data set in Form1.

Solution 3: Have a static provider class and store there your info that you want from different Forms. You can set and get these values from anywhere in your program.

Solution 4: ... there are many other ways. These were the simplest ones.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Private Sub RadGridView1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles RadGridView1.KeyDown
If e.keycode=keys.Enter then
   InvoiceEntry.txtsnam.text=RadGridView1.Currentcell.value
  End If
End Sub
```